# Force log out a user: Socket.IO

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have developed an app with PHP and node.js most of my app were built using PHP however on real-time part of my webapp I use node.js and socket.io My question is ..

How can I handle a user that is logged in in a multiple client? I am planning to force logout a user when he/she tries to log in from another client. is it possible to attain this logic and how? thnx

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket) {
    var secret = socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].query.secret;
    clients[secret] = socket;
    console.log('Client Connected');
    // Notification
    app.on("notification",function(data){
        socket = clients[data.recipient];
        if(socket != undefined){
            console.log('worked');
            socket.emit('notify',data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a unique id per user to the socket via handshake and maintain a global object on the server containing all connected user ids with their socket.id (key/value pairs).

When a client connects you check if the object has a key with the user id, which indicates the user is already connected from an other client.

- If false, you add the user id and socket id to the object.
- If true, you can easily get the socket.id of the old connection from the object and close this one. Then you set the socket.id of the new client in the object.

When a client disconnects you delete the key with the user id from the object.

This method works as long as you have only one socket.io instance simultaneously (no cluster, etc.), otherwise you have to use a central storage like Redis to maintain a list of all connected user ids.

If you need some more details or examples please let me know.

**Example**

I have not tested the below code, but this should be the most simple solution for you.

Of course you have to replace all `user_id_here` with the id of the user that connects.

```
var user_connected = {};

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket) {

// Check if user is already connected
if(user_connected.hasOwnProperty(user_id_here)) {
  // If true, disconnect previous connection
  user_connected['user_id_here'].disconnect();
}

// Add current socket to object
user_connected['user_id_here'] = socket;

var secret = socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].query.secret;
clients[secret] = socket;
console.log('Client Connected');
// Notification
app.on("notification",function(data){
    socket = clients[data.recipient];
    if(socket != undefined){
        console.log('worked');
        socket.emit('notify',data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: can you give some example?